# NamedQuery and inner join associaton

Tags: hibernate, hql

I want to join a table using an inner join association, but I don't know how to write it in the HQL syntax.

I want to write this "select * from persona p inner join trabajador t on t.id_persona=p.id" but in the HQL syntax. I want to put that sentence in a Named Query.

I greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score -2):

```
select p from Persona p inner join p.trabajador t
```

This is basic stuff, covered by [the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins). Read it.

Comment: HQL doesn't have an `on` clause?